# remove part of the new url php from link post

Tags: php

I would like to be able to click on a link that has specific information within it -

```
<a href="index.php?content=quiz-demo-1id=series-99">
```

id=series-99 is the information that I would like to be able to use as a variable on page - `index.php?content=quiz-demo-1`

1-page#1 - `mysite.com/Page_1`

2- Link on mysite.com/Page_1: click here - `<a href="index.php?content=quiz-demo-1id=series-99">`

3-new page url - `mysite.com/index.php?content=quiz-demo-1`

4 - new page code:

```
<?php
$quizname = $_GET['id'];
?> 

  <h2><?php echo $quizname?></h2>
```

I want the: `id=series-99` to drop off of the new url.

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression on this (I have corrected your url and added an ampersand):

```
$link = "<a href='index.php?content=quiz-demo-1&id=series-99'>";
$regex = '/(id=[^&"\']+)/i'; // capture everything except the characters in the brackets
$link = preg_replace($regex, "", $link);
echo $link;
```

However, it would be probably safer to use the mentionned `parse_url()` if you are not familiar with regular expressions.